# Search user profile with ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have two models, `user` and `profile`. The user has one profile.

```
# profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end

# routes.rb
resources :users do
  resource :profiles, except: [:index, :show]
end

# users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.includes(:profile)
  end
end

# users/index.html.erb
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% if user.profile %>
    <%= user.name %>
    <%= user.interest %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now, I want to add `ransack` gem to search user profiles. Here is my current setup:

```
# routes.rb
resources :users do
  collection do
      match 'search' => 'users#search', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
  end
  resource :profile, except: [:index, :show]
end

# users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = User.ransack(params[:q])
    @users = @search.result.includes(:profile)
  end

  def search
    index
    render :index
  end
end

# users/index.html.erb
<%= search_form_for @search, url: search_users_path, method: :post, do |f| %>
  <%= f.search_field :name_cont, placeholder: 'Name' %><br>
  <%= f.search_field :interest_cont, placeholder: 'Hobby' %><br>
  <%= f.submit 'Search %>
<% end %>
```

However I got this error:

```
NoMethodError in Users#index

undefined method `name_cont' for Ransack::Search<class: User, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search

<%= f.search_field :name_cont, placeholder: 'Name' %><br>
```

What's wrong with my code? Should I nest the search routes to the profile instead of user, so it looks like this:

```
# routes.rb
resources :users do
  resource :profile, except: [:index, :show] do
    match 'search' => 'profiles#search', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
  end
end
```

Then, how to setup the rest? Thank you.

Comment: Ransack by convention requires you to create fields such as <attr>_cont. User model must contain an attribute `name` that is the issue i believe.

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli the thing is, the name and interest is contained in Profile model which belongs to User model.

Comment: then apply ransack on Profile not user model like : `@search = Profile.ransack(params[:q])
    @users = @search.result.includes(:user)`

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli I need the index action to be in the users controller and the search action in the profiles controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, I don't read the documentation carefully. I just need to use these in the view:

```
<%= search_form_for @search, url: search_users_path, method: :post, do |f| %>
  <%= f.search_field :profile_name_cont, placeholder: 'Name' %><br>
  <%= f.search_field :profile_interest_cont, placeholder: 'Hobby' %><br>
  <%= f.submit 'Search %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add ransacker method to your User model. Example can be found [here](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/using-ransackers#6-passing-arguments-to-a-ransacker).

in User.rb

```
ransacker :name_cont, formatter: proc { |v|
  data = User.joins(:profile).where('profile.name = ?', v).map(&:id)
  data = data.present? ? data : nil
}, splat_param: true do |parent|
 parent.table[:id]
end
```

I have not tested this code.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I still didn't get it.